# Getting a stack overflow exception when normalizing a vector

Tags: c#, s

I'm making a `Vector` class in C#, with a normalized parameter, which is the vector normalized. However, when I'm trying to calculate the normalized Vector, I get a stack overflow exception. Is there a better way to do it? Here is my code (inside the constructor):

```
namespace Vector3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector3 vector = new(3, 4, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(vector.magnitude);
            Console.WriteLine(vector.normalized);
        }
    }



    class Vector3
    {
    
        public float x, y, z;
        public readonly float magnitude;
        public readonly Vector3 normalized;

        public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;

            this.magnitude = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(this.x, 2) + Math.Pow(this.y, 2) + Math.Pow(this.z, 2)));
            this.normalized = new Vector3(this.x/this.magnitude, this.y/this.magnitude, this.z/this.magnitude);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's really hard to help with just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: (And are you really using C# 4, which came out in 2010? Unless your question is specific to C# 4, I'd just tag it c#...)

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad. I'm not using cs4, I'm using the latest .net core.
I'll post the rest of my code.

Comment: Okay, you're calling the `Vector3` constructor *within* the `Vector3` constructor, unconditionally. I'm not surprised that creates a StackOverflowException... how do you expect that constructor call to ever complete? (The "outer" one will make an "inner" constructor call, which in turn will make *another* constructor call, etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have infinite recursion in the constructor. While you creating `Vector3`, you create another `Vector3` inside the constructor for `normalized` value. And this cycle never ends and finally gives you `StackOverflowException`

You can use lazy creation of `normalized` value as shown below.

```
using System;

namespace Vector3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector3 vector = new(3, 4, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(vector.magnitude);
            Console.WriteLine(vector.normalized);
        }
    }

    class Vector3
    {
        public readonly float x, y, z;
        public readonly float magnitude;
        
        private Vector3 _normalized = null;
        public Vector3 normalized => _normalized ??= new(this.x/this.magnitude,
                                               this.y/this.magnitude, this.z/this.magnitude);

        public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;

            this.magnitude = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(this.x, 2) + Math.Pow(this.y, 2) + Math.Pow(this.z, 2)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked as expected, but I'm unfamiliar with this syntax. Can you explain?

Comment: What part of the syntax needs additional commenting? In general, here we have the `normalized` property (not a field), which 
returns the value of the `_normalized` field if such value exists. And if the `_normalized` field is `null`, then the value will be created, stored into the `_normalized` field and then returned  (this is what the `??=` operator is used for).

Comment: @Woul: `?==` is a "null-coalescing operator": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator, and `=>` is a "lambda expression": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: So the ??= operator checks if a value is null, right?

Comment: Yes, the "??=" checks if a value is null... and then "lets you do something" ("coalesce the value") if it is.  For more details, please read the links I cited above.

Comment: Got it! Thank you all so much for helping me

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I'm trying to calculate the normalized Vector, I get a stack overflow exception

You are creating a new `Vector3` inside the `Vector3` ctor, which leads to "infinite" recursive calls ending in StackOverflow exception. Remove the call or make it some kind of lazy initialization. Or expose it with separate `GetNormalized` method.

Another option is to "break" the recursion, for example you can create another private ctor and pass `isNormalized` parameter (which would work better with readonly public contract):

```cs
class Vector3
{
    public float X { get; }
    public float Y { get; }
    public float Z { get; }
    public float Magnitude { get; }
    public Vector3 Normalized { get; }

    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z):this(x,y,z, false)
    {
    }

    private Vector3(float x, float y, float z, bool isNormalized)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;

        Magnitude = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2) + Math.Pow(Z, 2)));
        Normalized = isNormalized ? this : new Vector3(X/Magnitude, Y/Magnitude, Z/Magnitude, true);
    }
}
```